# Multiple instance of producers sharing the same producer name

Tags: apache-pulsar

I have a REST API that pushes the inflow request to a Apache Pulsar topic. The producer has a name (say, "api-integration-producer"). As I run multiple instances of this service (typically in Kubernetes), the service fails to start, complaining, the producer with the name ("api-integration-producer") is already registered with the Pulsar broker.

So, this means, I cannot run multiple instances of the service with the producer that produces to the same topic, or, with a producer that that shares the same name. However, I have solved this problem by generating a random producer name (append a uuid to "api-integration-producer").

Does this have an impact on the exactly-once scenario? What is the right way to name & run the Pulsar producers?

Answer (score 0):

Random producer name is fine for most cases.

Something to think about:   https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/it/effectively-once-semantics-in-apache-pulsar.html

You have to choose access mode.

Are you using a partitioned or non-partitioned topic?

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-messaging/#access-mode

https://github.com/apache/pulsar/wiki/PIP-68:-Exclusive-Producer